# How to wrap code inside a function makes that code is not working?

Tags: php, function, http, server

I have this code and it works perfectly:

```
if(in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], array('localhost', '127.0.0.1'))) // localhost
{
    $root = '';
}
else
{
    if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) // https
    {
        $root = 'https'.'://'.$_SERVER['HTTPS_HOST'];
    }
    else // http
    {
        $root = 'http'.'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    }
}
```

I echo it this way:

```
<img src="<?php echo $root.htmlspecialchars($path, ENT_QUOTES); ?>" />
```

I want to wrap the code inside the function like:

```
function root() {
// that code
}
```

And then echo it similar way to this:

```
<img src="<?php echo root().htmlspecialchars($path, ENT_QUOTES); ?>" />
```

How to do it? Because my example doesn't work.: (

Comment: The answer I marked works faster, because there is only one return. Using your answer I have the return 3 times. I gave you thumb up, thanks.

Comment: no speed type of thing raised in my code. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function doesn't return any value, so there's nothing to echoing...
Try adding `return $root` at end of your function:

```
function root()
{
    //that code
    return $root;
}
```